# Set bearer token HttpClient .NET not work

Tags: .net, post, request, authorization, httpclient

NET framework 4.7.2 and I am trying to make a Http call to an api with authorization filters.

The problem is that apparently the access token is not being assigned correctly since the response of the request returns a 500 error with the message "Internal server error".

I think the problem is in my call because via postman the request is executed correctly when I assign the "Bearer token" in the postman.

below I leave the code:

```
    public static async Task<TResponse> GenericPost<TRequest, TResponse>(string url, TRequest request, string token)
    {
        string responseString = string.Empty;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var requestPayload = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestPayload))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // = false: Error 500 internal server error
                {
                    responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
            }

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResponse>(responseString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any chance to inspect the differences of the two headers? The header sent from your httpclient vs the one sent by postman. May the logs of the api could provide more information what causes the server error :-)

Comment: maybe one positive aspect: 500 means the dev of the api should take care of the problem.

Comment: The API is perhaps expecting other headers to be present, try to add the User-Agent header